# I want to extract the strings from file name

Tags: ksh

one_two_three_four_five.rtf

I need five in A variable

I need four in B variable

And remaining in C variable

Should read from the last character

Note after 2 underscore from the last. There could be many underscores but should take has C variable.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What is your attempt so far? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve,

Answer (score 0):

For example using parameter expansion

```
#!/bin/ksh
string="one_two_three_four_five.rtf"
base=${string%.rtf}
a=${base##*_}; base=${base%_$a}
b=${base##*_}; base=${base%_$b}
c=$base
echo "$a - $b - $c"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s="one_two_three_four_five.rtf"
source <(sed -r 's/(.*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)[.].*/C="\1"; B="\2";A="\3"/' <<< "${s}")
# Result:
echo "A=$A, B=$B, C=$C"
A=five, B=four, C=one_two_three
```

Explanation:
`sed -r` No need for escaping backslashes
`(.*)_` Matches largest string until underscore with the condition that there are underscores left for matching the remaining string
`([^_]*)` String without underscore
`[.]` A dot without special meaning
`"\1"` First remembered string
`<<< "${s}"` Input for `sed` is like `echo "${s}" | sed ...`
 `<(..)` Simulates a file, so sourcing these will execute the commands.

Comment: for A it is printing five.rtf

Comment: I would have that result when I delete `[.].*` or put that in the last remembered string. I don't see why it doesn't work for you. You can change "${s}" into `${s%.*}`, but I don't see why it doesn't work for you. Or soes your string s ends with a second dot: `s="one_two_three_four_five.rtf."` ?